# How to count a depth level of nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object, nested, depth

I have an expample array of nested objects:

```
let arr = [{id: 0, children: []},
           {id: 1, children:[
             {id: 2, children: []},
             {id: 3, children: [
               {id: 4, children: []} 
             ]}
           ]}
         ];
```

I need to count depth level for each object. In all objects I have a parentId property too.

Result should be:

```
let arr = [{id: 0, depth: 0, children: []},
           {id: 1, depth: 0, children:[
             {id: 2, depth: 1, children: []},
             {id: 3, depth: 1, children: [
               {id: 4, depth: 2, children: []} 
             ]}
           ]}
         ];
```

I have an array of all the objects in a flat structure too.

Solutions?

Comment: What have you tried? Or is this your homework? :)

Comment: Seems like a prime use of Recursion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide your own efforts as a [mcve]

Comment: I am new at stackoverflow, I didn't notice that I should provide my own effort to not be hated :) I've tried to build a right loop for a few hours, but I am not familiar with recursion so much, and i got multiple errors during that. I needed that for a task, to get my first job as a front-end dedeveloper ,not homework :) Again, thanks for your answers and effort. I swear, in future I will public more informations, and my code to do it right. Hawk :)

Answer (score 8):

Just make a function that takes an array and a `depth` parameter that adds that depth to all objects in an array. Then call it on the `children` array with an incremented depth:

```js
let arr = [{id: 0, children: []},{id: 1, children:[{id: 2, children: []},{id: 3, children: [{id: 4, children: []} ]}]}];

function addDepth(arr, depth = 0) {
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    obj.depth = depth
    addDepth(obj.children, depth + 1)
  })
}

addDepth(arr)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to check if array exists with `(arr || []).forEach()` or `arr = []`

Comment: I agree @Pavlo and probably a good idea to make sure `arr` and `children` are actually arrays. I left this kind of code out to make the basic method as clear as possible.

Comment: i would go with Ikram solution, because then the teacher would think he OP is super good at JavaScript

Comment: @Pavlo --  Except ikram solution doesn't actually add depth to any of the objects - it just returns a number.

Comment: You are right, it just looked complicated, so i assumed it was correctly coded, without looking into it

Comment: Thank you very much for your anwers. It helped a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You could iterate the arrays and add a depth.

```js
const
    depth = d => o => {
        o.depth = d;
        (o.children || []).forEach(depth(d + 1));
    };

let tree = [{ id: 0, children: [] }, { id: 1, children: [{ id: 2, children: [] }, { id: 3, children: [{ id: 4, children: [] }] }] }];

tree.forEach(depth(0));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addDepth(arr, depth) {
  arr.map((entry) => {
    entry.depth = depth;
    addDepth(entry.children, depth+1);
  })
}

addDepth(arr, 0);
```

Comment: Why use `map`? Why would you want to return an array?

Comment: @MaxBaldwin He is not returning anything

Comment: I think that's the point @Pavlo, if he's not returning anything, why make an array? Why not just `forEach`?

Comment: The reasons are twofold:

First, I just like map over forEach... personal preference.
Second, I intended to actually use map to return a new array but immediately realized that would be a silly thing to do, but I just kept "map" there.

But really, I just like map... it "reads" better imo, even though it is, indeed, strictly incorrect in this case

Mark - feel free to use forEach, instead

Comment: @LeroyStav I wouldn't down vote you for this, but I think it only reads better if you haven't spent a lot of time with functional programming. I think this reads very strangely to others. Also if the data structure is large using `map` when you don't need to return value hurts performance — every time you use it you create an array, which is then ignored and later garbage collected. Of course, it's your code…

Comment: @Pavlo, yes that was my point. Also, Leroy, I did not down vote, but you should use `forEach` if you are not returning anything. Other devs who read this code will be confused. Your code is not for you. It is for them.

Comment: Like I said, I had started with something else in mind :-)  You're correct, of course, but I think that sometimes the best way to learn something new is to come across it and then read up on it... so the guy sees ".map" and then looks it up, and now he's learned something new.  Also, sorry for implying you downvoted... it just felt that you did, you know?  I'm new at actually attempting to answer questions and I'm happy for the constructive criticism.  As to your point - yes, performance will be worse with my solution, but let's be honest, this isn't something I would ever actually use map for

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a function that would be count for you.
try this one.

```
function depth(o){
  var values;
  if (Array.isArray(o)) values = o;
  else if (typeof o === "object") values = Object.keys(o).map(k=>o[k]);
  return values ? Math.max.apply(0, values.map(depth))+1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. This just returns `7` when I run it and doesn't add the depth to the objects.